# lines and bar with date produce a big rectangle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to display lines and bar according to date in a single graph in python.

I am using matplotlib and python2.7

If i create the lines and bar with index instead of dates, it looks ok.
But if i create lines and bar with date as x index, i only see a big rectangle.

Here is the code

```
def draw_graph():
    x = [ datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()+ i * 100)  for i in range(1,26) ]
    #x = [ i  for i in range(1,26) ]
    ys = [ [12.8, 11.7, 11.0, 10.2, 9.7, 9.2, 8.8, 8.3, 7.9, 7.6, 8.7, 12.0, 13.8, 14.9, 16.0, 16.6, 17.2, 17.9, 18.9, 19.7, 20.3, 20.8, 20.3, 19.9, 19.5],
                [17.2, 16.5, 15.6, 15.1, 14.4, 14.0, 13.6, 13.3, 12.8, 12.5, 13.2, 14.0, 15.7, 17.0, 17.8, 19.0, 19.7, 20.4, 21.3, 22.1, 22.5, 22.8, 22.3, 21.8, 21.4]
                ,[0.0, 1407362982.0, 1376380000.0, 1244750888.0, 1281503386.0, 1345770126.0, 1233699697.0, 1281798998.0, 1204362605.0, 1292156436.0, 1317519540.0, 359873335.0, 481384505.0, 425220178.0, 436946318.0, 357935188.0, 411935743.0, 778855000.0, 569431637.0, 967452677.0, 707153362.0, 784057555.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] ]

    lines=[]
    plt.xlabel('x label')
    fig = plt.figure(1)  # the first figure
    ax=plt.gca()

    index = 0
    for y in ys:
        plt.ylabel('y label')
        plt.title('graph.title')
        if index == len(ys)-1:#last y axis
            print index
            ax2=ax.twinx()
            line = ax2.bar(x, y, color='C' + str(index), alpha=0.5, label='bar')
        else:#all other y axis
            if 1: #time
                ax.format_xdata = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
                ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
                line, = ax.plot_date(x, y,'-',label='line1')
                fig.autofmt_xdate()
            else:#index
                line, = ax.plot(x, y, '-',label='line2')
                yloc = plt.MaxNLocator(10)
                ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)
        index = index + 1
        lines.append(line)

    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
    plt.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    draw_graph()
```

Here is bar and line graph with date as x axis

[image: big rectangle instead of bars]

Here is the same code using index instead of date as x axis

[image: bar and lines with index]

Comment: I am not going to debug your uncommented code. But if you change the step size with `x = [ datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()+ i * 100)  for i in range(1,2500, 100) ]`, you will see that somewhere in your code your bar plot misaligns the bars with the axis and changes their width. They don't even have all the same width. The line plots seem to be displayed as expected. Maybe that's a hint, where to look for the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two problems.

- **The bars are much too wide.** The default bar width is `1`. In case of datetimes, this is one day. However your data points are only 100 seconds appart. Hence you would want to make the bar width similar to the distance between two data points. In this case e.g.

  ```
  ax.bar(x, y, width=1./24/60., ...)
  ```
- **The formatter is not applied.** Due to the use of twin axes it would be necessary to apply the formatter after having drawn to the axes. I.e. the line

  ```
  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(...)
  ```

  should come after the loop.

In total this could look like

```
import datetime, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

def draw_graph():
    x = [ datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()+ i * 100)  for i in range(1,26) ]
    print x
    #x = [ i  for i in range(1,26) ]
    ys = [ [12.8, 11.7, 11.0, 10.2, 9.7, 9.2, 8.8, 8.3, 7.9, 7.6, 8.7, 12.0, 13.8, 14.9, 16.0, 16.6, 17.2, 17.9, 18.9, 19.7, 20.3, 20.8, 20.3, 19.9, 19.5],
                [17.2, 16.5, 15.6, 15.1, 14.4, 14.0, 13.6, 13.3, 12.8, 12.5, 13.2, 14.0, 15.7, 17.0, 17.8, 19.0, 19.7, 20.4, 21.3, 22.1, 22.5, 22.8, 22.3, 21.8, 21.4]
                ,[0.0, 1407362982.0, 1376380000.0, 1244750888.0, 1281503386.0, 1345770126.0, 1233699697.0, 1281798998.0, 1204362605.0, 1292156436.0, 1317519540.0, 359873335.0, 481384505.0, 425220178.0, 436946318.0, 357935188.0, 411935743.0, 778855000.0, 569431637.0, 967452677.0, 707153362.0, 784057555.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] ]

    lines=[]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax2=ax.twinx()
    index = 0

    for y in ys:
        plt.ylabel('y label')
        plt.title('graph.title')
        if index == len(ys)-1: #last y axis
            line = ax2.bar(x, y, color='C' + str(index),  width=1./24/60., alpha=0.5, label='bar')
        else: #all other y axis
            line, = ax.plot(x, y,'-',label='line1')
            ax.format_xdata = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

        index = index + 1
        lines.append(line)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    ax.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
    plt.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    draw_graph()
```

[image]